# Problemas con Chatgpt y Base de datos

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, inteligencia-artificial, gpt

Tengo un serio problema con mi código. Este trabaja de tal manera que puedas comunicarte con ChatGPT y este dependiendo de lo que le digas, lo use como consultas a una base de datos. El código realmente funciona con una base de datos muy simple la cual tiene 3 datos y 2 columnas "nombre" y "fecha" (es una tabla de cumpleaños)

```
#base de dato y api
from langchain.sql_database import SQLDatabase
bd = SQLDatabase.from_uri("sqlite:///cumpleanos.db")

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('login.ini')
api_key = config.get('login', 'api_key')
openai.api_key = api_key

import os
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = api_key
api_key = os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")

#crear llm
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model='gpt-3.5-turbo')

from langchain_experimental.sql import SQLDatabaseChain
cadena = SQLDatabaseChain(llm = llm, database=bd, verbose=False)

formato= """
Dada una pregunta del usuario:
1. crea una consulta sql
2. revisa los resultados
4. devuelve el dato
5. si tienes que hacer alguna aclaracion o devolver cualquier texto que sea siempre en español
#{question}
6. si la pregunta no tiene consulta en la base de datos, devolver una respuesta con tu conocimiento actual
"""

def consulta(input_usuario):
    try:
        consulta = formato.format(question = input_usuario)
        resultado = cadena.run(consulta)
    except Exception as e:
        print(llm(input_usuario))
    else:
        print(resultado) 

Input = input("Ingrese lo de chatgpt: ")

consulta(Input)
```

Este es el codigo, el tema es que al momento de cambiar la base de datos "cumpleanos.bd" por una mas grande, esta me arroja el siguiente error

> Got unknown type d File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\Chatgpt con
> teams\configurar.py", line 83, in consulta   resultado =
> cadena.run(consulta)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ TypeError: must be real number, not str
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\Chatgpt con teams\configurar.py", line
> 85, in consulta
> print(llm(input_usuario))
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\ARPHER\Desktop\Chatgpt con teams\configurar.py", line 91, in 
> consulta(Input) TypeError: Got unknown type d

donde hace referencia la "d" del error como la primera letra del texto que le envio a ChatGPT (que por ejemplo, si le escribo a ChatGPT "cual es el ultimo dato de la base de datos?" el error fuera "type c"), esto ocurre cuando cambio la base de datos por una mas grande la cual tiene 18 columnas y 20.000 filas de datos. Se que el error me dice que el dato deberia ser un numero real y no una cadena de texto, pero la cosa es que cuando la base de datos es la otra base de datos pequeña y simple, puedo escribir texto normalmente. La base de datos grande solo tiene columnas de tipo "TEXT" y "DATE" que incluso son los mismos tipos que tiene la pequeña y simple "TEXT" y "DATE".

Ayuda ¿Por que pasa esto?

Comment: El mensaje de error es elocuente: `must be real number, not str`. En algún lado de tu código se espera un valor numérico, pero está recibiendo una cadena (string).

Comment: Eso lo se, al final especifique eso. El tema es que el codigo que mostre funciona perfectamente, la cosa es que cuando cambio "cumpleanos.db" por una base de datos mas grande, este muestra el error del numero real. Para mi la unica diferencia es que uso una base de datos mas grande pero no veo la relación en que con una pida un numero real y otra no

Comment: El mensaje también te dice que los errores están localizados en las líneas `85` y `91` del archivo `configurar.py`. En vez de obligarnos a leer todo el código para luego adivinar la lógica, podría ayudar que empieces por indicar lo que hay en esas líneas del código. No debes hacer una interpretación subjetiva de los errores: *Para mi la unica diferencia es que uso una base de datos mas grande pero no veo la relación en que con una pida un numero real y otra no*. Hay un error, y debes revisar lo que está diciendo el mensaje de error en vez de pensar: *es injusto, debería funcionar*.

Comment: Imagino que no me explique bien, pero en el propio mensaje explico que el codigo funciona, cuando uso la base de datos "cumpleanos.bd" no existe ningun fallo, el programa funciona, pero al usar otra base de datos aun mas larga, esta me arroja el error que mostre. Uso exactamente el mismo codigo, por eso mi expresión ya que mi conocimiento no es suficiente para entender el problema. Cabe recalcar que en la base de dato grande se usa datos tipo "TEXT" y "DATE" al igual que la base de datos pequeña la cual si funciona

Comment: Ya, pero es que, por poner un ejemplo, en la nueva base de datos el archivo `configurar.py` podría estar mandando datos de forma equivocada. Imagina que ahí se crean las tablas, o se hacen inserciones o yo que sé y esos datos no coinciden. Como ya dije, no debes dar nada por supuesto, sino revisar. Dinos qué hay en las líneas `85` y `91` de `configurar.py`. Supongo que revisaste ese archivo ¿no? Los mensajes de error no son para ignorarlos, sino para hacer lo que se dice en ellos.

Comment: La linea 85 es la linea de codigo "print(llm(input_usuario))" y la 91 es la "consulta(Input)"

Comment: Prueba poniéndolo así: `print(llm(int(input_usuario)))`

Comment: Ya, pero lo que busco es colocar una consulta en texto que sea algo como "En que estado se encuentra la petición KLO12007", normalmente con la base de datos normal yo le pregunto "Cuando cumple Pedro?" Y me responde con la fecha de su cumpleaños (que se encuentra en la base de datos), colocar el "int" no seria un error?

Comment: Yo no conozco Python, pero viendo algunos ejemplos, parecería que puedes mejorar tu código usando `prompt` en vez de `input`. [Revisa aquí por ejemplo](https://llm.datasette.io/en/stable/python-api.html) o bien [en este otro enlace](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/chains/foundational/llm_chain).

Comment: Vale, hechare un vistazo a ver si eso me ayuda a solventar el codigo. Gracias

Comment: El problema principal, es que encapsulaste tu error, y ahora te esta dando otro error que nada que ver con tu error... Estas saliendo por el except , no pongas un texto de cualquier cosa, muestra la e y todo el chorro de error REAL que esta tirando...

Comment: Acabo de probar cambiando la exception y que me imprimiera la "e" y me imprime el mismo problema del "numero real", tambien elimine el "try catch" para ver que problema me imprimia y lo mismo. Si necesitan algun tipo de información extra para entender el problema con gusto se las doy. Igualmente el exception que coloco ahi es porque al hacer una pregunta que no sea una consulta, tambien da error por lo que lo uso para que ChatGPT escriba su respuesta normal sin consultar a la base de datos